# Prove that $x^r$ with $r=a+ib$ or $r=a-ib$ defines real solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Prove that $x^r$ with $r=a+ib$ or $r=a-ib$ defines real solutions in terms of trigonometric functions with argument $\ln x$ multiplied by exponential function $y(x)=x^{(a+ib)x}$ or 
$y(x)=x^{(a-ib)x}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Answer (score 1):

Let $r_1=a+ib, r_2=a-ib$ are complex conjugates where $a\in\mathbb R$ and $b>0$ is real. So the following function $$y=C_1x^{r_1}+C_2x^{r_2}$$ is the solution. Since $$x^{ib}=(\text{e}^{\ln x})^{ib}=\text{e}^{ib\ln x} $$ and the Euler's Formula, we get $$x^{ib}=\cos(b\ln x)+i\sin(b\ln x)$$ Therefore,  $$y_c(x)=x^a[C'_1\cos(b\ln x)+C'_2\sin(b\ln x)]$$

Comment: You nailed it!! $\large \color{blue}{\bf \ddot\smile}$